# non-existing parameter for 'sonata.page.admin.block'

Tags: php, symfony-cmf

I am nearly finished with installing most of the Sonata bundles in Symfony CMF. For now. my final step is finishing with the Sonata PageBundle. I installed all needed dependencies and needed bundles, I changed several config or routing files from app/config using this manual (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

The problem appears when I want to to do the 'last' step;

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataPageBundle
```

I receive this error:

{ParameterNotFoundException: The service "sonata.page.admin.block" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "sonata.block.container.types". Did you mean this: "sonata.page.block.container.class"?}

Okay, it is obvious that a dependency parameter is missing, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact problem.

My **sonata_page** & **sonata_block** from app/config/config.php;

```
sonata_page:
  multisite: host
  use_streamed_response: true # set the value to false in debug mode or if the reverse proxy does not handle streamed response
  ignore_route_patterns:
      - ^(.*)admin(.*)   # ignore admin route, ie route containing 'admin'
      - ^_(.*)          # ignore symfony routes

  ignore_routes:
      - sonata_page_cache_esi
      - sonata_page_cache_ssi
      - sonata_page_js_sync_cache
      - sonata_page_js_async_cache
      - sonata_cache_esi
      - sonata_cache_ssi
      - sonata_cache_js_async
      - sonata_cache_js_sync
      - sonata_cache_apc

  ignore_uri_patterns:
      - ^/admin\/   # ignore admin route, ie route containing 'admin'

  page_defaults:
      homepage: {decorate: false} # disable decoration for homepage, key - is a page route

  default_template: default # template key from templates section, used as default for pages
  templates:
      default:  { path: 'SonataPageBundle::layout.html.twig',          name: 'default' }
      2columns: { path: 'SonataPageBundle::2columns_layout.html.twig', name: '2 columns layout' }

  # manage the http errors
  catch_exceptions:
      not_found: [404]    # render 404 page with "not_found" key (name generated: _page_internal_error_{key})
      fatal:     [500]    # so you can use the same page for different http errors or specify specific page for each error

sonata_block:
#    context_manager: sonata.page.block.context_manager
default_contexts: [cms]
blocks:
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts:   [admin]

    #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
    #    contexts:   [admin]

    sonata.block.service.text:
    sonata.block.service.rss:
    sonata.page.block.container:
    sonata.page.block.children_pages:
```

There is a similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034340/what-is-sonata-block-container-types-parameter-in-sonatapagebundle), but unanswered for 4 months, Google doesn't have any info (that I was able to find) on this issue.

If someone can point out what is going wrong and where, I would love to hear it..

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for SonataPageBundle by the CMF project yet. So I guess the "symfony-cmf" tag is incorrect?

Comment: As far as I know all is based on Symfony CMF (even do SonataPageBundle seems to be unsupported) so imho the 'symfony-cmf' is pretty correct. But let's not get to deep into those details..